Why are road-bike freewheel ratchets so loud?
(This is related to this question here, but while that one is focusing on quality of the gear (higher end vs lower end), my question focuses on the style of the bike.)
I have made the experience that some freewheeling ratchets - in my observation especially on road bikes - are excessively loud. Example:

I have a good touring bike that I use as my everyday commuter. It is a mid-range touring bike with steel frame, drop bar, and good Shimano components (XT).
When I'm coasting / freewheeling this bike is close to perfectly
silent. I take great pride in the well maintained and oiled
machinery, and about the loudest thing are the slick road tires on the
asphalt. You could properly sneak up on someone on that bike.

Now, I also have a road bike. It is a solid mid to upper range carbon
race bike (Scott), again with Shimano components (don't remember
which set exactly). As long as I'm pedalling this bike is just as silent as my commuter... But coasting on this bike is LOUD. Like, every
time I take it out for a spin I am again startled as to how load the
freewheel ratchet is... As in, when I silently ride behind someone in
traffic, and suddenly stop pedalling, the sound will make them jump
and turn their head.


Is my observation accurate, do loud freewheel ratchets coincide with road bikes? Or is it something else?
Is there a reason for this? Does the sound serve some purpose?

Check youtube videos on loud freewheels and you'll for example also find a fair share of bmx related videos, so it's clearly not just road bikes. And in bmx one reason IIRC is that it was a trend at some point a couple of years ago, maybe still is.

At least for Chris King, for example, I recall reading that he set out to make a quiet freewheel mechanism, but then customers were indicating to him/his company that they liked it, so in the end he kept the design that way. Other designs probably followed suit. Here is a video interview segment which mentions this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE3EYlTN2RI

Same reason why motorcycles or sport cars are loud: Because customers want it that way.
As you have observed, it is technologically possible to build quiet freehubs (just as it is possible to build quiet motorcycles). But historically, loud freehubs have come to be associated with high quality. Today this isn't true anymore, as both low- and high-quality freehubs can be both quiet and loud. But customers do still demand loud freehubs, so manufacturers make them.
The is some slight practical use of loud freehubs, which is warning pedestrians: Bells (which are mandatory in some countries, while horns and similar are forbidden) are often not heard by pedestrians, because as the human ear deteriorates with age, sensitivity to the high frequencies generated by bells decreases. Also the short "ping" of a bell makes it hard to locate the origin of the sound. Meanwhile, the continuous low-frequency buzz of a freehub is easily heard and located by most people and also gives an indication of speed.

I find this answer amusing. IF customers demand loud freehubs, why doesn't Shimano make them?

Not all customers demand them, but some do. Chris King, tune etc. satisfy this demand. Shimano, Onyx etc. satisfy the demand of customers who want silent freehubs.

@juhist Shimano makes noisy hubs as well, the FH-MT500 is an example.

@Rеnаud I recently sold a very similar hub and it wasn't particularly loud. Clicky yes, but nothing like a Chris King or similar BZZZZZZZZZ type sound.

@MaplePanda my mistake, the noisy one was indeed the one you linked. Indeed, not as noisy as typical high-end road hubs, but definitely a step up over all the others I have.

The explanation I've had is that race bikes are often ridden in tight pelotons, some riders value noisy freehubs, as it can be used to warn another rider of their arrival (or pedestrians) while covering wind noise. Although this explanation has some limits, as too much noisy hubs will make impossible to locate the closest one.
It's more a question of hub design than road versus "the rest", pawl-based freehubs being often more often noiser than freehubs with star ratchets (invented by DT Swiss, but now used by others as well as the patent expired) ...but noisy hubs tend to be favoured more than quiet hubs in this particular segments. Some hub manufacturers even make it a "preference" on my Mavic ones for example, there's a rubber part that I can remove to make the hub noisy — with the rubber part and well greased, it's quiet. Mavic uses this hub design (based on the star ratchet) across their full range, so it's not a road specificity.
In my case, the noisiest hub I had was in fact on a e-touring bike, that came with a Shimano hub (FH-MT500) - the other Shimano hubs that are at home are quiet though (an old LX and a Tourney).

There are several possible aspects to that. It may be that some of them in combination are true in your case, all of them, or none.
Less damping
If you want to make a mechanism waterproof you drench it in lots and lots of grease. This has two additional effects on the loudness:

It slows down the movement of the ratchet mechanism making it sound less pronounced
It dampens the sound propagation through the hub in general, reducing its volume.

Road bike hubs which are more optimized for performance instead of being maintenance free under all weather conditions may use less and/or less viscous grease, which reduces both effects from above.
Different (more unusual/"annoying") sound
Higher end freewheels may use different ratcheting mechanisms which might sound more unusual and/or annoying to your ears. This might already cause a "man, this is loud" psychoacoustic effect although it maybe isn't louder when simply measuring the loudness with a sound meter.
Some manufacturers (and riders) also may aim for some distinct freewheel sound for recognition reasons.
Resonance
Carbon frames tend to be quite good resonance bodies. Therefore it may be that the frame is in good resonance with the sound of the freewheel and is therefore just amplifying the sound better. This can cause that the same freewheel appears really loud in one frame and not so loud in the other.
Aero rims might have a similar effect.

The answer is simple:
Many people like loud hubs.
There is not a real difference of bike type as most hub manufacturers use the same freehub in their road and MTB hubs.Most often MTB and Road Hubs are identical except width and axle diameter.


It is a solid mid to upper range carbon race bike (Scott), again with Shimano components (don't remember which set exactly). As long as I'm pedalling this bike is just as silent as my commuter... But coasting on this bike is LOUD

Really?
I think the main reason for freewheels being loud is that non-Shimano components are used.
The bike manufacturers cheat by saying "Shimano components", and then omitting that it refers to only some components, not to all components. I found that my first non-BSO bike shop bike was sold as "XT" bike, but only the rear derailleur was XT and the bottom bracket and rear hub were non-Shimano "black comp" no-name parts. Needless to say, both the bottom bracket and the rear hub axle failed very soon after purchasing the bike.
Shimano components would mean that the hubs too are Shimano. As I have found that Shimano hubs are practically silent (only when they become very old age, a very slight coasting sounds can be heard), it's likely that your road bike doesn't have Shimano hubs. It may have Shimano cranksets, Shimano bottom bracket, Shimano derailleurs, Shimano cassettes, Shimano chains, Shimano pedals, Shimano shifters, Shimano brakes, Shimano brake levers, but certainly it doesn't have Shimano hubs.
I believe this is a huge mistake made by bike manufacturers. Shimano hubs are some of the best hubs available.
My e-bike (Cannondale Synapse Neo EQ, sadly no longer made) came with some no-name "Formula" hubs. The rear one is loud like a machine gun. Unfortunately/fortunately (depending on viewpoint) the wheels had only 28 spokes and other design mistakes like tubeless-ready rims (read: rims so tight tube changes are practically impossible) and didn't stand the test of time, so I had the opportunity to replace the wheels with Shimano-hubbed 36-spoke wheels with double-eyeletted non-tubeless-ready rims.
Stick with Shimano components. They are exceptional quality and value. As a bonus, the hub bearings are easily serviceable with standard tools as long as you don't need to change the bearing cups (but the bearing cups last the longest, far longer than bearing cones, so this isn't usually needed).

Shimano isn't really known for the quality of their hubs und rims (they still use cup and cone bearings)...
And calling Formula no-name is really a stretch.
